# Using AWS Lambda with Elastic Search, getting Undefined from the search client

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I'm trying to learn Nodejs while simultaneously learning AWS platform.

I'm building a Lex application that uses a Lambda function with an AWS Elastic Search instance.

My search is basic and is finding what it needs to, the thing is when I test my handler it doesn't receive the data. When I log the results to the console, it seems like the search result object doesn't get passed back to the handler function until after the handler has already printed the results. Using some console logs I get this output:

```
Starting handler function
Starting search
{ dialogAction:
   { type: 'Close',
     fulfillmentState: 'Fulfilled',
     message: { contentType: 'PlainText', content: undefined  } } }
Top hit: [object Object]
```

The content item is undefined, but should instead be the Top Hit object that is returned from search.js. I can see the TopHit object is being found, but why is the index.handler function printing before the search response is returned?

My Lambda Handler function in index.js:

```
const search = require("./search.js");
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

console.log("Starting handler function");

const questionReq = event.currentIntent.slots.question;
//console.log(questionReq);
// call Exported function from search js.Pass in string as question
const results = search.searchQuestion(questionReq);

const eventResponse = {
    "dialogAction": {
    "type": "Close",
    "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
    "message": {
      "contentType": "PlainText",
      "content": results
    }
  }
};

callback(null, eventResponse);
};
```

My Elastic Search in search.js:

```
const client = require('./connection.js');

exports.searchQuestion = function(question)
{
    var topHit = "";
    console.log("Starting search");
    client.search({
      index: 'library',
      type: 'dsa',
      body: {
        query: {
          match: { "q": question }
        },
      }
  }).then(function (resp){
      topHit = resp.hits.hits[0];
      console.log("Top hit: " + topHit);
  }, function(err){
      console.trace(err.message);
  })
    return JSON.stringify(topHit);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you log the data within event? Just to make sure your question is defined. Aside from that, I would make sure resp.hits.hits is returning a value, if it isn't - you've done something wrong on the elasticsearch side (likely not indexing properly), which does not appear to be in the scope of this question.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your content value should be """". I could be wrong. Is that undefined?

Comment: @RamziC. Good question, but when I log the results of topHit from search.js I get the correct JSON response, so it isn't an issue with Elastic Search, I think it is a problem with my code.

Comment: @chandrasugur Yes you are correct, sorry I was double checking the assignment of topHit and forgot to change it back. In this case, when I let topHit = "", I get a result of """".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your searchQuestion function is async, it is returning a promise.

Your code should look something like this:

```
const search = require("./search.js");
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log("Starting handler function");

    const questionReq = event.currentIntent.slots.question;
    //console.log(questionReq);
    // call Exported function from search js.Pass in string as question
    search.searchQuestion(questionReq)
        .then(result => {
            const eventResponse = {
                "dialogAction": {
                    "type": "Close",
                    "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
                    "message": {
                        "contentType": "PlainText",
                        "content": results
                    }
                }
            };
          callback(null, eventResponse);
      });
};
```

Your Elastic Search in search.js:

```
const client = require('./connection.js');

exports.searchQuestion = function(question)
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       var topHit = "";
       console.log("Starting search");
       client.search({
         index: 'library',
         type: 'dsa',
         body: {
           query: {
             match: { "q": question }
          },
        }
     }).then(function (resp){
         topHit = resp.hits.hits[0];
         return resolve(topHit);
     }, function(err){
         console.trace(err.message);
    });
  });
}
```

I hope this helps :).

Comment: @Nltin Vaja,I think this is the right direction, but that code is giving me an error: 

`index.js:16
        .then(result => {
         ^

TypeError: search.searchQuestion(...).then is not a function
    at Object.exports.handler (index.js:16:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (test.js:48:7)`

From what I see that means my searchQuestion still isn't returning a promise properly? What else am I missing?

Comment: Please try the above code again. Also, you might be able to try this as well --> return client.search .. which then should return that promise.

Comment: @Nltin Vaja That did it! Thank you :)

Comment: @astralbody888 No problemo, enjoy :)